# After upgrade from Angular 5 to 6 , I got many rxjs errors

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular6

After upgrade from Angular 5 to 6 , I got many rxjs errors

Although I have followed [the official guide](https://update.angular.io/), I still had many rxjs errors after updating my packages & following the steps of the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [rxjs github page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) , you might need to add the rxjs-compat to maintain compatibility, but you should remove it asap as it increase the package size, so as soon as you update your code, you would better remove it.

Using this command below will add rxjs-compat@6 which maintains compatibility

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```